# How to make an action happen on the current instance of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

So I want some HTML to appear, but only in the element where it was clicked. With more than one instance of this class it will appear in every instance, after the element of class `movieend`. (Every `<div class="moviepanel">` contains a `<hr class="movieend">`.)

I figure I should be able to use the 'this' word somehow like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".moviepanel").click( function(){
        $("<p> Test </p>").insertBefore($("this .movieend"));
    });
});
```

I could do this the long way by giving each `moviepanel` an id, but I figure there must be a better way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: You would use `$(this).find('.movieend')` or `$('.movieend', this)`.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to familiarize yourself with the jQuery API. It should not take more than a day to have a look at every jQuery function and get a feeling for how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong:

```
$("<p> Test </p>").insertBefore( $("this .movieend") );
```

Correct:

```
$("<p> Test </p>").insertBefore( $(this).find(".movieend") );
```

Alternatively:

```
$(this).find(".movieend").before("<p> Test </p>");
```